# Windows-Steam-client on playOnLinux/ wine only installs native linux games

Tags: wine, games, steam, playonlinux

I have the native steam client for Windows installed on my system. Now I wanted to play a Windows-only game and installed Steam thru POL in WINE. Everything works fine and i can start and log in to steam thru wine, but when I want to install a Win-game, it tells me, that my OS is incompatible, just like in the native Linux-client.

It seems, as if steam somehow shared some systemwide recources even from within the wineprefix.

can somebody tell me how to fix this?